# How to set JDBC connectionstring in liferay portal wizard?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I just installed the tomcat server 8.0 for liferay 7 and trying to set the connectionstring in the wizard. However receiving this error:

> An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the database.

How can I set the location of the hypersonic db?

error:

> 07:51:36,217 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-1][HikariDataSource:95]
>   HikariPool-3 - Starting... 07:51:37,220 ERROR
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-1][HikariPool:534] HikariPool-3 - Exception during
>   pool initialization. java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
>   invalid authorization specification   at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:327)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:113)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.(JDBCConnection.java:3618)   at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:318)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:260)   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:346)

[image]

Comment: Non-programming related questions are out of scope for stackoverflow. Please consider bringing them to the Liferay forums or other platforms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure using following path:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:E:/workspace/hsql/lportal;hsqldb.write_delay=false
```

**or in portal-ext.properties**

```
    jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
    jdbc.default.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:E:/workspace/hsql/lportal;hsqldb.write_delay=false
    jdbc.default.username=sa
    jdbc.default.password=
```